# vertical-align: middle without using display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text appear as shown in the attached image. Please take a look here for what I have done so far (code included): http://jsfiddle.net/FLb6K/1/

[image]
**The reason I can't use `display: inline-block` is because I want to the have the ability to change the position of the elements easily from the CSS without touching the HMTL using `float`.**

For example, the image above, there are two `<div>`s: one has an image and one has text. Using CSS `float` I can make the image appear on the left by just adding `float: left`

Comment: The defeated the whole point of being able to re-position elements using floats,

Comment: The vertical-align property only works with inline or table-cell elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Used below code:

```
<style>
div{border:solid 1px #000000; margin:5px; padding:5px;}
.maindiv{min-width:100px;height:300px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
.div1{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
.div2{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
</style>

<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="div1">text</div>
    <div class="div2"><img class="div2" width="240" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/ISO_639_Icon_hi.svg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But not I can't use float

Comment: Hi again Loai, but there is no float in my code. Hope you are doing a lot today.

Comment: I understand - that is the problem. I want to be able to change the position of the image to appear on the right or left of the text using CSS so using Floats and not HTML

Answer (score 0):

Then use `display:table-cell;` to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Use it instead of `inline-block` - @Loai

Answer (score 0):

if your text will be always a ONE LINE TEXT, you can just set a line-height with the div's height.

Or, display:table; on the div that the text is inside, and the text element display:table-cell; with vertical-align middle

Comment: No it will be different, and I tried to workaround the issue using line-height, I tried to set line-height to 100% and the div to 100% but no hope

Comment: you can try to use a absolute positioned div with top:50% and a negative margin-top of half of its height

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you want to support you could use a transform to align vertically.

Assuming your containing div has a height set, and the div you want to center has a class of 'vert-center':

```
.vert-center{
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
            transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9J9xD/
Browser support is at about 82% according to caniuse

And here a good article on centering in css: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the div order, remove the floats and make both elements display: table-cell:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/FLb6K/7/

**CSS:**

```
#abreast {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#abreast div {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
#abreast div.left {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#abreast div.right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#abreast div.right img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="abreast">
    <div class="left">
        <div>
            <p>Text Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img alt="image" src="http://taimapedia.org/images/5/5f/Placeholder.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mate, I am trying to change the order using CSS using float

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The title is "vertical-align: middle without using display: inline-block" the answer I posted answers this. If you want to change the order of the blocks with floats then you need to edit the question to reflect this. You will receive a more succinct answer by doing this.